# Multiple belongs_to on same model and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got two `belongs_to` associations to the same model then below

For `simple_form`

```
= f.association :from_user
= f.association :to_user
```

In the `chats` table I've got `from_user_id` and `to_user_id`

User model

```
has_many :from_user_chats, :foreign_key => :from_user_id, :class_name => 'Chat'
  has_many :to_user_chats, :foreign_key => :to_user_id, :class_name => 'Chat'
```

Chat model

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :from_user, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :to_user, class_name: 'User'
    belongs_to :chattable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This however gets me below error:

```
undefined method `from_user_id' for #<Chat:0xcf283e0>
```

is there a reason why?

Bactrace:

```
block in #<Class:0xd660bf0>#_app_views_chats__form_html_haml__904465522_69002796
app/views/chats/_form.html.haml, line 5
#<Class:0xd660bf0>#_app_views_chats__form_html_haml__904465522_69002796
app/views/chats/_form.html.haml, line 1
#<Class:0xd660bf0>#_app_views_chats_new_html_haml___186355583_68493228
app/views/chats/new.html.haml, line 3
```

Comment: All look al right to me. Any backtrace?

Comment: I've just updated with backtrace

Comment: Is your association working correctly in the console?